# Sencha Touch 2 - Scrollable Dataview overlaps other items in Panel

Tags: extjs, touch, dataview, scrollable

I would like to add a section which also scrolls with the dataview, I would prefer not to add this in the dataview and the store it links to because if an item is tapped it pushes another view, hence it will cause an error trying to find a non-existent view.

Basically I would like all items in the Container to be scrollable instead of just the dataview.

Here is the code in this view:

```
    config:{
    title:'Learning Journey',
    layout:'fit',

    items:[
        {
            html:'<p>This will be overlapped when the text is too long or when scrolled.</p>'
        },
        {
            xtype:'dataview',
            store:'MenuStore',
            itemTpl:'<div class="menuData {panelColour}"><h1>{panelTitle}</h1><br> {panelDesc}'
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm sure there is a simple answer to this problem but I cannot get my head around it (I'm  a Sencha Touch 2 noob).

Thanks!

Here is an image which shows the problem: http://i58.tinypic.com/2v1nqk4.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the layout of your wrapping container. `fit` ensures that all items of the container will fill out the entire container. So width and height of your html container are set to 100% each. But this also applies to your dataview. So both items will fill out the wrapping container completely.

To fix it just set the layout of your wrapping container to `vbox`. So the dataview will be inserted directly under your html container.

If you want your html container to be scrollable you have to add the `scrollable: true` property for it. But don't forget to provide some height!